# Python Regex Grouping finditer

Tags: python, regex, grouping, python-re

Input: `146.204.224.152 - feest6811 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:24 -0700] "POST /incentivize HTTP/1.1" 302 4622`

Expexcted Ouput:

```
example_dict = {"host":"146.204.224.152", "user_name":"feest6811","time":"21/Jun/2019:15:45:24 -0700",
"request":"POST /incentivize HTTP/1.1"}
```

My code is working for grouping individually,
eg:

```
for item in re.finditer('(?P<host>\d*\.\d*\.\d*.\d*)',logdata):
        print(item.groupdict())
```

`Output: {'host': '146.204.224.152'}`

But I am not getting the output by combining every group.
Below is my code:

```
for item in re.finditer('(?P<host>\d*\.\d*\.\d*.\d*)(?P<user_name>(?<=-\s)[\w]+\d)(?P<time>(?<=\[).+(?=]))(?P<request>(?<=").+(?="))',logdata):
           print(item.groupdict())
```

Comment: `\.\d*(?<=-\s)` obviously cannot be true. Probably you meant to skip something (some whitespace maybe?) between the subexpressions.

Comment: I used it to skip whitespace or  '-' symbol so that I can access the next word, Those expressions are working individually though. Some expression contains 
219.194.113.255 - - [21/Jun/2019:15:46:12 -0700] "PATCH /next-generation/niches/mindshare HTTP/1.0" 503 20246

Comment: Again, for `(?<=x)` to match after something, the immediately adjacent previous match must be literally `x`.  Your second subexpression looks for whitespace immediately before, so you can't glue it immediately after another expression whose match does not require whitespace at the end. Either take out the `(?<=...)`, if you actually want to match immediately after dot or digit, or insert an expression which skips whitespace between the two expressions if that's what you want to match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you paste two regular expressions back-to-back, they will only match text back-to-back. For example, if you combine `a` and `b`, the regular expression `ab` will match the text `ab`, but not `acb`.

Your combined regex suffers from this problem; you have melded together regular expressions which apparently work fine in isolation, but they didn't match immediately adjacent strings, so you have to add some padding to cover the intervening substrings in the input.

Here's a slightly refactored version with adaptations to add padding, and also a few routine fixes to avoid common regex beginner mistakes.

```py
for item in re.finditer(r'''
        (?P<host>\d+\.\d+\.\d+.\d+)
        (?:[-\s]+)
        (?P<user_name>\w+\d)
        (?:[^[]+\[)
        (?P<time>[^]]+)
        (?:\][^]"]+")
        (?P<request>[^"]+)''',
        logdata, re.VERBOSE):
    print(item.groupdict())
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/BsNLG7

Comment: I was sloppy and selected Python 2 for the demo, but it should not matter for this simple code. (The parentheses around the argument to `print` are optional in Python 2, but it works fine with the Python 3 syntax I used, too.)

Comment: The trailing `\d` on the user name is still dubious; unless you specifically are searching for user names which end with a digit, probably simply take it out - `\w+` will happily match numbers, too.

Answer (score 1):

I might simplify your regex pattern and just use `re.findall` here:

```
inp = '146.204.224.152 - feest6811 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:24 -0700] "POST /incentivize HTTP/1.1" 302 4622'
matches = re.findall(r'(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+) - (\S+) \[(.*?)\] "(.*?)"', inp)
print(matches)
```

This will generate a list of tuples containing the four captured terms you want:

```
[('146.204.224.152', 'feest6811', '21/Jun/2019:15:45:24 -0700', 'POST /incentivize HTTP/1.1')]
```

Comment: Actually, this is a single line of a big file.I need to create a dictionary with the keys as mentioned.Is there any way?

Comment: You can zip the output from `re.findall` ... but why do you need a dictionary?

Comment: `for item in re.finditer('(?P<host>\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+) - (?P<user_name>\S+) (?P<time>\[(.*?)\]) (?P<request>"(.*?)")',logdata):`                                                                                      I got out with this..Thank you .                                                                                           
  I was trying to read the input into a dictionary with keys(Host,username,Time...)